# Sprite Kit create animated object

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have the following code to create the animated texture:

```
-(void) setUpActions {
    SKTextureAtlas * atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"player"];

    // Running player animation
    SKTexture * runTexture1 = [atlas textureNamed:@"player1.png"];
    SKTexture * runTexture2 = [atlas textureNamed:@"player2.png"];
    SKTexture * runTexture3 = [atlas textureNamed:@"player3.png"];
    SKTexture * runTexture4 = [atlas textureNamed:@"player4.png"];
    SKTexture * runTexture5 = [atlas textureNamed:@"player5.png"];
    SKTexture * runTexture6 = [atlas textureNamed:@"player6.png"];
    SKTexture * runTexture7 = [atlas textureNamed:@"player7.png"];
    SKTexture * runTexture8 = [atlas textureNamed:@"player8.png"];

    NSArray * runTexture = @[runTexture1, runTexture2, runTexture3, runTexture4, runTexture5, runTexture6, runTexture7, runTexture8];

    runAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:runTexture timePerFrame:0.06 resize:YES restore:NO];

    SKSpriteNode * playerNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"player"];
    [playerNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:runAnimation]];
}
```

And this creates the sprite node and is added to the scene in another method:

```
-(SKSpriteNode *)createPlayer {
    SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
    player.position = CGPointMake(100, 160);
    player.name = @"player";
    player.zPosition = 100;

    return player;
}
```

Doing it this way, I'm forced to create an object that has a static image and overwrite it with the animated texture. How do I create an object that is animated without it having a default static image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animate action can only be executed on an actual instantiated SKSpriteNode object, however, you can just create a 'blank' node, then run the animate action on it:

```
SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode node]; // instead of the static player sprite
```

Or, if you want the blank node to have a specific size, so that it responds to touches/collisions in a specific area before it's animated, for example, try a clear-coloured rectangle:

```
SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:(CGSizeHere)];
```

Or perhaps you want to use the first frame of the animation as the texture of the sprite:

```
SKTexture *temp = runTexture[0];
SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:temp];
```